# How do I move an object in one direction with a single keypress until the direction is changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When I start the program and press the first key the program freezes. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work and give me a possible solution to my problem?

```
if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
    key = False
    while key == False:
        schlange.move(0, -50)
if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
    key = True
    while key == True:
        schlange.move(0, 50)
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    key = False
    while key == False:
        schlange.move(-50, 0)
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    key = True
    while key == True:
        schlange.move(50, 0)
```

---

```
def move(self, x_change, y_change):
    self.screen.fill(BLACK)
    self.x_change = x_change
    self.y_change = y_change
    self.startx += x_change
    self.starty += y_change
    self.rectsize = (self.startx, self.starty)
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, [self.startx, self.starty, self.width, self.height])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wrong idea. Your program will never leave the `while` loop because `key` is never updated in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be something like this

```
speed = (0, 0)

While True:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed = (0, -50)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed = (0, 50)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed = (-50, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = (50, 0)

    # --- all updates (without draws) ---

    schlange.move(speed[0], speed[1])

    # --- all draws (without updates) ---

    # ...
```

Comment: This works for what I asked for but now my collision detection doesn't work properly anymore. Any idea why ? Here my code: [link](http://pastebin.com/Y8U9ptML)

Comment: by the way - pygame has nice class `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size. And PyGame can use it to draw or `blit()`. It can be use to check collisions with another rect or point.

Comment: you check collision in wrong place - inside `for event`. `for event` do nothing if there is no event like key press or mouse move. You have to check collision outside `for event`. I my example I would put this in "all updates"

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah this really doesn't look like my code anymore. You kind of finished the game for me. I want to do all this myself and I'm going to use your code as a guideline now whenever I'm stuck. Maybe I should check out the basics of pygame again because I don't really know how to use pygame.Rect() and blit() ... Anyway thanks for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

The formatting in your code is off - but regardless - the code in each of the sections that look like:

```
key = False
while key == False:
    schlange.move(0, -50)
```

Will never complete.  That while loop will ALWAYS evaluate to True, because `key == False` is always true, and never changes.  So the loop will never end.